# how to see more than 1000 records in elastic seach

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am having following query in elastic

```
"query" =>[
                "multi_match" => [
                "fields" => ["prod_name", "prod_seo_name"],
                "type" => "phrase_prefix",
                "query" => $query
            ]
```

below is my URL

```
http://example.com/ppm2.0/search.html?q=fonerange
```

when I search in MySql DB with 'fonerange' on column 'prod_name', it returns 3000 records but I can see 1000 in elastic , How could I see other records?

Comment: Question is not clear enough. Please provide better information with examples.

Comment: @HatimStovewala plz see updated question

Comment: Let's take a look here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a limitation on the number of document that you can see by querying elasticsearch I believe it's around 10 000. If you need more you can use the scan and scroll API:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html